# Questions in other community do not get any attention

Tags: discussion

I have noticed that questions in other community get very, very few attention. For example, I post a question in StackOverFlow, it get at least 100+ views in the first hour, but questions that I posted in serverfault gets less than 20. Sometimes even 2-3.

Can we somehow, ask things here? Because, I think (I may be wrong) a lot people know in Stackoverflow what I am trying to ask. Is it offensive?

For example let us consider this issue:

**Apache doesnot load VirtualHost**

This is clearly a server related question, but a lot of people in the Stackoverflow community have come across this issue and can help with it.

Comment: You can ask on Stack Overflow *if your question is on topic*. (If SO did not have such a restraint, it'd be called "AskJeeves".)

Comment: The question may be on topic on SO, though. Depending on what's in it, impossible to tell from just the title.

Answer (score 7):

Stack Overflow is...special.  I don't mean that it's special because it was one of the first sites created; it's special because it's [**the largest site in the network.**](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic)

Naturally, it's going to be the one with the most eyes and attention on it, but that doesn't mean that the other sites aren't popular or don't have enough foot traffic on them either.

You'll note that there can be overlap on the network with other sites; for example, a question that's on topic on Stack Overflow may be on topic elsewhere.  But, that doesn't mean that it's alright to post the question in both places.

You'll also note that each other site in the network specializes on some other aspects, and the ask is that one posts their question **on the site which fits it best**.

I will note that your question *may* appear to be on-topic, as we do have an [apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache) tag.  But, if you do decide to ask your question, it does need to be objective and clear as to what's going on (adding debug information, what your configuration is, and what you've attempted will go a long way to keeping it on topic).  If the community decides it's a good question but doesn't belong here, they may elect for it to be migrated.

Comment: Largest site in the network? By far... How far Stack Overflow is from the next site: Stack Overflow..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................Super User.

Comment: Often the much lower question volume allows the smaller sites to be more effective in their moderation. Most others are good at getting rid of off-topic stuff much more quickly than we can on SO. There's also less eyes on each question as the smaller sites cater far less to people looking to play FGITW. There will often be questions sitting on SO with views in the dozen rather than hundreds, as well, so I'm not entirely sure there's any basis to this question whatsoever